# ros_controlConfig.cmake not found

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Following tutorial on ros_control at http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_control.

Created package with `catkin_create_pkg MYROBOT_control ros_control ros_controllers`
The i tried to `catkin_make` and got error

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "ros_control" with
  any of the following names:

    ros_controlConfig.cmake
    ros_control-config.cmake
```

What could be the issue?

ros-control and ros-controllers packages are installed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221359/ros_controlconfig.cmake-not-found/) by [yasagitov](https://answers.ros.org/users/23174/yasagitov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 223 on 2015-11-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might not have updated the CMakelists.txt and package.xml files.You can find these files from the following link.
https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_demos/tree/master/rrbot_control

Hopefully you will stop getting the errors.

---

Originally posted by [Zubin Priyansh](https://answers.ros.org/users/24060/zubin-priyansh/) with karma: 161 on 2015-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0